# Remove trailing zeros until 2 decimals in PHP

Tags: php

I've tried casting to `float` and `number_format` but float will always round at two and number_format is fixed on the amount of decimals you specify.

So how can I do this like the following conversion

```
11.2200 -> 11.22
11.2000 -> 11.20
11.2340 -> 11.234
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php this might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use float casting

```
echo (float) 11.2200;
echo "<br/>";
echo (float) 11.2000;
echo "<br/>";
echo (float) 11.2340;
```

and you have to check number of digits after decimal point and than get value like below :

```
$val=(float) 11.2000;
if(strlen(substr(strrchr($val, "."), 1))<2){
    echo number_format($val,2);
}
```

Comment: `echo (float) 11.2000` will return `11.2` not `11.20`

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that the second one will return 11.2 instead of 11.20

Answer (score 1):

```
$money1 = 68.75;
$money2 = 54.35;
$money = $money1 + $money2;
// echo $money will output "123.1";
$formatted = sprintf("%01.2f", $money);
// echo $formatted will output "123.10"
```

This might help, You can use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) given by PHP.

Comment: This will round the number to the nearest decimal, I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the round() function for this.

i-e round(number,precision,mode);

Example:

echo(round(11.2200,2));

Output

11.22

Thanks

Comment: Rounding `11.2340` to 2 decimal places will give `11.23` not `11.234`

Comment: Like Peter said this doesn't return the desired value

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone If you use Round function and set the precision it will round of the amount and give you the amount according to the precision you set.

11.2200 when use with round(11.2200,2) will output the 11.22 as it will first round of it then will set the precision

Comment: Yes, therefore it is not dynamic. I believe Bart wants it to be dynamic...?

Comment: Yes, it can either be 10.12 or 10.123 but not lower than 2 decimals

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone, Bart asks for 2 decimal precision i-e static value hence i suggest the respective answer.

Comment: He asked to remove zeroes **until** 2 decimal places, `11.234` is not to 2 decimal places, it's 3...

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone ok ok

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need a fix for this anymore, but I just ran into the same problem and here's my solution:

```
$array = array(11.2200, 11.2000, 11.2340);
foreach($array as $x)
{
    // CAST THE PRICE TO A FLOAT TO GET RID OF THE TRAILING ZEROS
    $x = (float)$x

    // EXPLODE THE PRICE ON THE DECIMAL (IF IT EXISTS)
    $pieces = explode('.',$x);

    // IF A SECOND PIECE EXISTS, THAT MEANS THE FLOAT HAS AT LEAST ONE DECIMAL PLACE
    if(isset($pieces[1]))
    {
        // IF THE SECOND PIECE ONLY HAS ONE DIGIT, ADD A TRAILING ZERO TO FORMAT THE CURRENCY
        if(strlen($pieces[1]) == 1)
        {
            $x .= '0';
        }
    }
    // IF NO SECOND PIECE EXISTS, ADD A .00 TO IT TO FORMAT THE CURRENCY VALUE
    else
    {
        $x .= '.00';
    }
}
```